# 811 just marked my utilities, can I mow my lawn?

Tags: safety, utilities

I had 811 mark my utility lines. They were here today.They marked with both spraypaint and flags.

The markings are valid per their rules for 30 days. It will be about 2 weeks before I can get the landscaping work done. In the mean time is it OK to mow the spraypainted marks?

Comment: At least they didn't try spraypainting the snow like they did here not long ago...that didn't work out well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO! Do not disturb the markings enough to make them disappear. Mow around the markings.